# hunspell should correct using russian 'ё' character

Tags: hunspell

When I run the following command with hunspell spellchecker

```bash
$ echo 'еще' | hunspell -d ru_RU
```

I get the response

```bash
Hunspell 1.7.2
*
```

which says the spelling is ok, but I want hunspell to tell me that the correct spelling is `ещё`. Is it possible?